# Find a formula for leaves in tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction, trees, data-structure

Given a tree $T$ with $n$ nodes, every node that isn't a leaf has 2 children, can i drive  a formula for number of leaves in a such tree $T$?

My idea: i read this post:[Full binary tree proof validity: Number of leaves $L$ and number of nodes $N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847896/full-binary-tree-proof-validity-number-of-leaves-l-and-number-of-nodes-n?rq=1)
, but it is about full binary tree, our problem maybe not full binary tree.

Comment: What is your definition of full binary tree?  The tree you describe is what I call a [full binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $T$ has $n$ nodes, $\ell$ of which are leaves; then the sum of the degrees of the nodes is

$$2+3(n-\ell-1)+\ell=3n-2\ell-1\,,$$

since the root has degree $2$, each of the other $n-\ell-1$ non-leaves has degree $3$, and each leaf has degree $1$. This is twice the number of edges, so $T$ has $\frac{3n-1}2-\ell$ edges.

On the other hand, $T$ is a tree, so it has $n-1$ edges, and we have the equation

$$\frac{3n-1}2-\ell=n-1\,,$$

so that

$$\ell=\frac{n+1}2\,.$$

The reason that $n$ has to be odd, as this formula clearly implies, is that the non-root nodes of $T$ come in sibling pairs, so there is an even number of them, and the root makes an odd total number of nodes.